# EL can retrieve a subclass's property?

Tags: jsf, el

```
class Cat{
}

class Tiger extends Cat{
    public String getZooAddress(){
        return "cityZoo";
    };
}

Bean{
    public Cat getCat() {
        return new Tiger();
    }
}
```

I noticed that `#{bean.cat.zooAddress}` actually displays "cityZoo".  How does it work? I imagined that `#{bean.cat}` represents a Cat and trying to call `getZooAddress()` would result in an "property not found" error. Is the container automatically doing the downcasting from Cat to Tiger?

Comment: EL doesn't use static typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression Language utilizes Reflection to find the appropriate property accessor methods on the referenced object.

Here is more information on why Expression Language happens to work this way.

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/07/unified-jsp-jsf-expression-language.html#evaluation-of-el

Comment: Link is dead :/